# how do you run a python script as a shell script?

Tags: python

I have a python script that its firs line is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I am in the same directory and when I do this on the currently directory:

```
ls -l | grep aix

-rwxrwxrwx  1 virtual wheel       5617 Dec 16 14:31 aix.py
```

when I do this:

```
./aix.py
```

I get:

No file directory exists, how is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `#!/usr/bin/env/python` as your first line?

Comment: His shebang is correct. Env is a file not a folder.

Comment: What do you get if you just run `/usr/bin/env python` on your command-line? What do you get if run you `pwd`?

Comment: @MeetTitan Exactly, inspectorG4dget's point was that if it was wrong, then you would get that error. (`/usr/bin/env/python` doesn't exist)

Comment: @nneonneo, this is the entry  1 #!/usr/bin/env python, when I type /usr/bin/evn python from the command line, I go to the python prompt.

Comment: Can you run the file with an absolute path?

Comment: If the error is actually that no file *directory* exists, is it possible that your script is running successfully but that an error about a missing directory is coming from inside the script? (i.e., code you haven't posted)

Comment: @MicahSmith, I can run the script from the command line with this: python aix.py, it successfully runs. But when I do ./aix.py, it says no file or directory, it is extremely strange to me.

Comment: Can you paste the error *exactly* as it appears?

Comment: @user1471980 Or can you paste a screen grab

Comment: @BhargavRao, just update the original post.

Comment: @user1471980 This is crazy stuff. The script is executable but doesn't run. What kind of sorcery is this? Did you try `sh aix.py` (though it is a stupid proposal to do)

Comment: @BhargavRao, I've put the aix.py into a shell script, it works for now. But I was really curious, why ./aix.py was not working.

Comment: Yeah even I'm eagerly waiting for an answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The file is probably not in your PATH. Change your current directory to the location of the file, then run the command.

Comment: It doesn't matter if he runs it as `./myexecutable`

Comment: Are you sure about that? All configurations? Sure doesn't work like that on my machine.

Comment: @datasci, If you run a Unix/Linux box that's how a relative path to an executable works. `./` is the shorthand of `/path/to/current/dir/` Put a filename after that and it becomes the same thing as `/path/to/current/dir/file` which is how you call executables.

Comment: @MeetTitan, thanks for sharing. To clarify, in Ubuntu I've experienced situations like this one, where if I am at $HOME and run ./sqldeveloper, for example, I get a "No file or directory" error, but if I am $SQL_HOME and I run ./sqldeveloper, the program works perfectly. Same experience with Python scripts. It appears my case may be unique. Best.